# How to use gcc 4.5?

Tags: unix, gcc, binary, download, gcc4

http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

This page has the binaries. Which one would work for Fedora?

Comment: gcc is usually already installed in Linux.

Comment: @Kinopiko: I have 3.4.something. I want to use 4.5

Comment: If you have gcc already then just download it and build it from source.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using the [GCC RPM for Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/gcc?_csrf_token=45cfb9439afc897c82dca90a06987c90a717348f).

From command line:

```
yum install gcc
```

Comment: A: I did that. It installed gcc 3.4.something. I want to use gcc 4.5!

Comment: @cambr - as suggested, build it by yourself from source.